# getBoundingClientRect to know if an element is above a particular vertical point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using getBoundingClientRect to know if an element is above a particular point in the page. So I do this:

```
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

if (rect.top < bottom_limit) {
   return true;
}
```

I think this is working well, but in some debugging I have found that some elements return 0 for all top,bottom,right,left. For example: [Example1](http://jsfiddle.net/ImBcmDth/SxXXk/) and [Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/ImBcmDth/SxXXk/1/)

```
<span id='a'>
    <span id='b'>This is some crazy text.</span>
</span>

#b {
    float: left;
}
```

and

```
#b {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I am concerned about getting all zeros. Why is this happening? Can I trust this method for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Try [`display: inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/zqDkq/) instead of `position: absolute`.

Comment: Teemu, I am parsing sites, and I would like to know if this is a trustfull method, given that I can't control the CSS.

Comment: Looks like some browsers (Chrome) need the checked element to be a block-level element. If you can't control the CSS, a short answer would be no, you can't fully trust `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: That's really bad news. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using document.getBoxObjectFor(el), or try el.offsetTop/offsetLeft/offsetWidth/offsetHeight. Think they may be Mozilla only though, and not sure if they will work with non-block level elements.